# Why does the eclipse installation of new software failed?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have just download the eclipse and go to Help -> Install new Software, choose the `Helios - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/helios`

> as the repository, then the exception
>   coms out as ,
>
> org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core.ProvisionException:
>   Unable to connect to repository
>   http://download.eclipse.org/releases/helios/compositeContent.jar
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.CacheManager.updateCache(CacheManager.java:357)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.CacheManager.createCache(CacheManager.java:205)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.CompositeMetadataRepositoryFactory.getLocalFile(CompositeMetadataRepositoryFactory.java:74)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.CompositeMetadataRepositoryFactory.load(CompositeMetadataRepositoryFactory.java:99)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.factoryLoad(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:57)
>     at

I am sure I could download the compositeContent.jar file from `http://download.eclipse.org/releases/helios/compositeContent.jar` for I have downloaded it within the firefox.

So what's wrong?

Comment: Maybe you are missing proxy settings that are available in Firefox.

Comment: Why firefox settings matters?

Comment: It;s not that they matter for Eclipse but if you have a proxy set up in Firefox and the download link works from there you should put the same proxy settings in Eclipse at Window -> Preferences -> Network Connections.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since eclipse would typically catch a completely failed connection, your error suggests you are getting part of the update site but not all of it. There's quite a few files in an update site, mainly xml and jars.

If a proxy isn't the issue as Bobby suggested i would first try creating a new workspace and updating then to make sure eclipse hasnt cached anything corrupt. Otherwise you might have to resort to creating a local mirror of the update site.

Comment: Surprisely, I could do it today.